# PhoneGap Upload data in Background

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Requirement:

I have a PhoneGap application. I collect photos, text data and audio recordings through my app. Now I want to upload this data to the server.

How do I upload my data to servers even if the application is suspended or put to background.
     If yes, any pointers would be really helpful. I am developing the app for Android and iOS.

Thanks a lot for all the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following:

You can use following PhoneGap plugin to upload data in the background for iOS.

http://www.codefromjames.com/wordpress/?p=154

I start the upload process when the application is in use and continue upload in the background until 5 mins (you can choose the time, my upload should never take more than 5 minutes)

Now I am looking in how it can be done in Android and PhoneGap. I will update the post when I find anything for Android.

Thanks
Anup